# Corda: How to save a Instant state variable as UTC in the valult DB?

Tags: corda

I have a contract state with a variable of Instant type which represents a UTC value. But when the PersistentState saves it to the DB, the DATETIME value in the DB represents the local date time instead of UTC. 
  Can some one help me to have the DB value as UTC?
  Thanks.

\Sean

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution -
 1. val theUTC = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
 2. In schema,
    @Column(name="entryDateTime")
    val entryDateTime: LocalDateTime
 3. In generateMappedObject,
    this.theUTC.toLocalDateTime()

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of `Instant` use:

```
private final OffsetDateTime txTimestamp;
```

2. In your custom schema:

```
@Column(name = "tx_timestamp") private final String txTimestamp;
```

3. In your state's `generateMappedObject` pass:

```
this.txTimestamp.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
```

4. Also if you have an API, I used this in my `RequestModelMapper` object:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
private OffsetDateTime txTimestamp;
```

Comment: Thanks, Adel. But I cannot use String for the column because the DB has DATETIME2 (or DATETIMEOFFSET) as the data type. Liquibase would complaint String and DATETIME being not compatible. Is there another way?

Comment: Then define your column as `OffsetDateTime` instead of `String`; it should work.

Comment: OffsetDateTime does not help. I still get local datetime in the DB.